# How do I prevent browser caching in Spring MVC when an Exception occurs?

Tags: spring-mvc, cache-control

I want to make the browser cache my responses, but only in case the return status is 200.

I know how to enable cache-control header in Spring MVC. However, when my code throws an exception that is handled by an *Exceptionhandler* that returns a HTTP error status (e.g. 404) then the response header still has the cache-control which makes the browser cache the response. This is not the desired behavior. When my code returns a HTTP error status I do **not** want that response to be cached by the browser.

I have tried writing my own *HandlerInterceptor* that sets the cache-control header in the *postHandle* or *afterCompletion* methods. However I see that these methods do not get invoked, or get invoked after the response is sent to the browser.

I use Spring 4.1.6. My controller is a *RestController* that returns a *ResponseEntity*. It does **not** return a view that is then processed by a *ViewResolver*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251549/i-want-to-add-a-header-to-http-response-based-on-the-http-status-code-in-spring did you check this post? It is similar issue.

Comment: how did you add the cache-control headers in the first place?